# Exception calling WCF Service (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Please help, I'm getting the following exception when try to consume a WCF service from an ASP.NET web application:

````
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) +622
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() +320
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream() +115

[EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://<serverName>/<serviceName>/Autenticacion.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +357
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +979
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +114
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +149
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2755```

The WCF service is up and it works with local tests, but give this error in the application.
The url is correct in the Web.config file.
````

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo? I think `https://<serverName>/<serviceName>/Autenticacion.svc` should be `.../Authentication.svc` (see the h in auth)

Comment: The real url is 'https://btbext02/ServiceRans/Autenticacion.svc' and is exactly like that in the config file. I did put a generic value un the post for privacy reasons.

Comment: Can you access the url via your browser? Maybe it's not reachable?

Comment: Yes I can access to the service via browser.

Comment: Ok, so you can access the service running on server `btbext02` from your machine. Where is the ASP.NET website running? On another server? Is `btbext02` accessible from that server, too? And in whose user context is the website running? Maybe the that user isn't allowed to access `btbext02`?

Comment: Check your web.config, make sure you set security mode="Transport" on both sides since it is https.

Comment: What is your web.config like? How do you call the WCF service? Is it called through the proxy class generated by Svcutil?